# Type Eq weirdness in Hashell

Tags: haskell

Learning how to write typeClasses in haskell

Wrote the following at first

```
data Trivial = ATrivial
instance Eq Trivial where 
  (==) trVal1 trVal2 = trVal1  == trVal2
```

and wonder why it does work ?
Indeed the following expression should not compile,

```
trVal1  == trVal2
```

cause `==` on `Trivial` is not defined, at best it should recurse indefinitely. Indeed if my understanding of Type classes is correct the only possible type of trVal1 and trVal2 is Trivial. That is constrainted by type argument of the Type Class `Eq Trivial`.

In any case even when I write this, it still works

```
data Trivial = ATrivial
instance Eq Trivial where 
  (==) trVal1 trVal2 = trVal1 :: Trivial  == trVal2 :: Trivial
```

I believe the proper way to write this is:

```
data Trivial = ATrivial
instance Eq Trivial where 
  (==) ATrivial ATrivial = True  -- Using pattern matching
```

Am I misunderstanding or not seeing something here ?
Can anyone help disambiguating this .....

## EDIT1

Upon writing the following in GHCI

```
ATrivial == ATrivial
```

I just get nothing back ? Is there a way to get the REPL to complain rather than silently killing the recurssion
In fact no idea what the REPL is doing

Comment: There's infinite recursion, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't compile.

Comment: You cause an infinite loop: you say two `Trivial`s `trVal1` and `trVal2` are equivalent, if `trVal1 == trVal2`, so this will keep calling itself.

Comment: I see the issue is that the repl does not even tell me there is an infinite recursion ... will update

Comment: How did you define this in the repl? For multiline statements, you should wrap these in `:{` and `:}`.

Comment: that you "get nothing" means that the code is running. What do you expect?

Comment: Ah got it, the issue is my install. I am using Intellij Haskell plugin, with it the prompt comes back as if nothing is happening. While if i launch ghci from the terminal myself, it hangs, which is what i expected. No idea what's wrong with the haskell intellij plugins

Comment: Could it be that there exist some GHCI option, that allows to ignore or kill silently an infinite loop ?

Comment: It can't know if the loop is infinite in all cases right? You can search for how to kill Haskell code after X seconds but...

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible for a computer program to automatically correctly determine whether or not any arbitrary program written in a Turing-complete language (like Haskell and most other “general purpose” languages) halts. This is a very important result in the theory of computation called the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: @David while that is true, it is nowhere near as obvious/inevitable that we should use Turing-complete languages, as most programmers think! The dependently typed languages deliberately avoid this, precisely to prevent accidental ⊥ recursion as in the OP; and though I'll admit that programming in Coq is much more difficult than in Haskell, this actually has little to do with the totality checker.

Comment: `==` on `Trivial` doesn't have to be defined when you are defining the instance, only when you finally *evaluate* a call, and by the time you do, the instance for `Trivial` *is* defined.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've spent a decent amount of time recently working on a project in Coq so I am certainly aware of that, hah. I thought my explanation was sufficient given the current context, but I definitely do agree that sub-Turing-complete languages can be very useful and are very important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiles because it's in general perfectly sensible to have recursive definitions, also for class instances. For example, an `Eq` instance for a list type would look like

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (List a) where
  Nil == Nil = True
  Cons h t == Cons h' t' = h==h' && t==t'
  _ == _ = False
```

Here, `t==t'` is also a recursive call to the “not yet defined” `==` operator on `List a`, but unlike in your example it's called with reduced arguments so this *will* terminate if called with finite lists.

Unlike Agda and Coq, Haskell generally doesn't prevent you from writing recursion that just loops forever without progress, again independent of whether you're defining a standalone function or instantiating a class method.